# how to arrange random dice faces (yahtzee) in numerical order

Tags: c#

So i have been working on yahtzee game, so far i have got the labels to display dice images at random, this is the code.

```
#region Declaration

Image[] diceImages;
int[] dice;
Random rand;

#endregion

#region Initialization

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    diceImages=new Image[7];
    diceImages[0] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_0;
    diceImages[1] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_1;
    diceImages[2] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_2;
    diceImages[3] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_3;
    diceImages[4] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_4;
    diceImages[5] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_5;
    diceImages[6] = Properties.Resources.dice_face_6;

    dice = new int[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    rand = new Random();
}

#endregion

private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        dice[i] = rand.Next(1, 7);

    lblDie1.Image = diceImages[dice[0]];
    lblDie2.Image = diceImages[dice[1]];
    lblDie3.Image = diceImages[dice[2]];
    lblDie4.Image = diceImages[dice[3]];
    lblDie5.Image = diceImages[dice[4]];
}
```

Can i arrange the dice images in numerical order, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.Sort` ([MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        dice[i] = rand.Next(1, 7);

    Array.Sort(dice);

    lblDie1.Image = diceImages[dice[0]];
    lblDie2.Image = diceImages[dice[1]];
    lblDie3.Image = diceImages[dice[2]];
    lblDie4.Image = diceImages[dice[3]];
    lblDie5.Image = diceImages[dice[4]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
    dice[i] = rand.Next(1, 7);
```

create an ordered list:

```
dice = dice.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

and then continue assigning the images.